# Fire command on client system from server

Tags: 12.04, command-line, scripts, session

I have two ubuntu systems one server and another is client.

So I have written one script on server, following are the code of script file:

```
Code for login into the client system

`sshpass -p prakash12 ssh -p 11111 prakash@localhost`
```

This command must have to fire on logged on client system.

```
${HOME}/temp/.git describe --always --tags HEAD
```

The first command executed successfully for logged on to the client system.But second command is get fired on server system insted fired on logged on system.

So how can I fired the second command on the client system from the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send command remotely, simply provide the command in quotes following the ssh log-in command, like this:

```
sshpass -p prakash12 ssh -t -p 11111 prakash@localhost '${HOME}/temp/.git describe --always --tags HEAD'
```

If you need to pass more command over ssh you have several options:

Use semicolon to separate the commands:

```
ssh -t -p 11111 prakash@localhost 'command1 ; command2 ; command3'
```

Use a [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) document:

```
ssh -t -p 11111 prakash@localhost << EOF
    command1; 
    command2;
    command3;
    command4;
    command5;
EOF
```

Comment: Your ans is working but after execution of 2nd command the connection to client system is closed. Means 1st command also lost the session. But I want to execute the 4/5 more commands after the 1st command i.e. login command is executed.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include this use case.